# Adding insecure registry in containerd

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

Trying to add insecure registry to containerd config as below:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      max_conf_num = 1
      conf_template = ""
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
        [plugin."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."test.http-registry.io"]
          endpoint = ["http://v048011.dom600.lab:5000"]
```

Even after adding it to `config.toml`, when pulling image from the insecure registry, it fails:

```
sudo ctr image pull v048011.dom600.lab:5000:5000/myjenkins:latest

ctr: failed to resolve reference "v048011.dom600.lab:5000/myjenkins:latest": failed to do request: Head https://v048011.dom600.lab:5000:5000/v2/myjenkins/manifests/latest: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

In `docker` we could just add the `insecure registry` to `daemon.json` file and docker would pull images from it, how can i achieve the same in `containerd` ?
Replacing docker as runtime in k8s cluster.

Answer (score 30):

`ctr` **does not** read the `/etc/containerd/config.toml`  config  file, this config is used by cri, which means `kubectl` or `crictl` would use it.

The error log `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`, shows that the registry is using http, but `ctr` is trying to connect it using https.  So if you want to pull the image from http, you should add the param `--plain-http` with `ctr` like this:

```
$ ctr image pull --plain-http <image>
```

The registry config doc is [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/docs/cri/registry.md).

You should be able to pull the image with `crictl`, remember to restart containerd.

```
$ sudo crictl -r /run/containerd/containerd.sock pull <image>

# or config runntime once for all
$ sudo crictl config runtime-endpoint /run/containerd/containerd.sock
$ sudo crictl pull <image>
```

Config example:

```
# /etc/containerd/config.toml
# change <IP>:5000 to your registry url

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."<IP>:5000"]
      endpoint = ["http://<IP>:5000"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."<IP>:5000".tls]
      insecure_skip_verify = true
```

Restart the service after configuration modification.

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Note, that in a multi-node cluster each node's `containerd/config.toml` must be updated.

Comment: This form of config is deprecated, please refer to https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md#configure-image-registry 
 and 
 https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/config.md#registry-configuration for details

Comment: I was same issue by ctr in Containerd. After install crictl have solved. crictl is awesome CLI tool like docker. it's command is same as docker commands.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. If trying to add insecure registry with k0s (which uses containerd/ctr), please note a `toml` file needs to be created at `/etc/k0s/containerd.d/something.toml` (with any name) as mentioned here: https://docs.k0sproject.io/v1.27.5+k0s.0/runtime/#k0s-managed-dynamic-runtime-configuration

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following config:

```ini
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      max_conf_num = 1
      conf_template = ""
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."test.http-registry.io"]
          endpoint = ["http://v048011.dom600.lab:5000"]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."test.http-registry.io".tls]
            insecure_skip_verify = true
```

should skip TLS verification for the test registry. See also the documentation on [registry TLS communication configuration](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/registry.md#configure-registry-tls-communication).

Edit: Please note the "s" in plugins, there is a typo in your configuration.

**NOTE:** Be sure to restart containerd aferwards:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

Comment: Thanks !! Even after adding the [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs] lines, still while pulling the image it hits the https connection to the insecure registry

Comment: It could be dependant on your containerd version, see also this issue on Github: https://github.com/containerd/cri/issues/1367

Comment: Thanks @Blokje5, i was using the ctr to pull image, the doc you provided asked to use crictl, but i still have no success with it.

Comment: Did you also check the containerd version? The insecure_skip_verify flag is a recent addition.

Comment: Yes containerd version is 1.4.3, thats the latest.

Comment: This form of config is deprecated, please refer to https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md#configure-image-registry 
 and 
 https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/config.md#registry-configuration for details

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I simply added `[[registry]]` field into `/etc/containers/registries.conf` file simply because I was using `crio`

```
[[registry]]
insecure = true
location = "IP ADDRESS"
```

and restart crio

```
systemctl restart crio.service
```

Please refer
https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/main/docs/crio.conf.5.md

Comment: You are using `cri-o` as CRI, it's different from those who use `containerd` as CRI