# Kubernetes with containerd : http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: containerd

I am setting up my K8s cluster with container as runtime.
Now when I am trying to pull a image using :

```
sudo ctr image pull 192.168.1.2:5000/my-alpine:latest
```

It is giving me an error :

> ctr: failed to resolve reference "192.168.1.2:5000/my-alpine:latest": failed to do request: Head `https://192.168.1.2:5000/v2/my-alpine/manifests/latest`: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

My /etc/containerd/config.toml

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
      endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."192.168.1.2:5000"]
      endpoint = ["http://192.168.1.2:5000"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."192.168.1.2:5000".tls]
      insecure_skip_verify = true
```

What am I missing here? When I am pulling an image from Kubernetes deployment and also getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

i also got the same error .i resloved it by following the steps given below

**sudo rm -rf /etc/containerd/config.toml**

**sudo su -**

**mkdir -p /etc/containerd**

**containerd config default>/etc/containerd/config.toml**

**sudo systemctl restart containerd**

**sudo systemctl enable containerd**

then after these steps open then file

**sudo nano /etc/containerd/config.toml**

find this line

**[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]**

add these lines below that line

```
   [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000"]


   [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000".tls] 
        ca_file = ""
        cert_file = "" 
        insecure_skip_verify = true 
        key_file = ""
```

then search this line   **[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]**

and add the below lines  below that line

```
         [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."registry-ip:5000"] 
          endpoint = ["http://registry-ip:5000"]
```

after this i restarted containerd

**sudo systemctl restart containerd**

its working fine after that

Answer (score 0):

ctr does not read the `/etc/containerd/config.toml` config file.
This config is used by the CRIs, which means `kubectl` or `crictl` would use it.
For ctr, you should add the param `--plain-http`:

```
sudo ctr image pull --plain-http=true <image>
```

The registry config doc is:
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/docs/cri/registry.md

Also, see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67310470/1106294

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your private registry is non-secure without https.
The I have below segment in containerd/config.yaml and it works for me.
I hope this helps.

> [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
> config_path = ""
> [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]
> [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs] [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."192.167.103.199:5000".tls]
> insecure_skip_verify = true
> [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]
> [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]       [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."192.167.103.199:5000"]
> endpoint = ["http://192.167.103.199:5000"]