# Insecure registry containerd in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

everyone.
I try to build k8s cluster (v 1.20) in my company.
I have some worker-node.
And I have been deployed some services already.

And now I have a task to create a custom image. The main question: where should I store them (images)? I made local docker registry. But containerd can't pull image from not secure registry.
And I find decision in net: update config.toml for containerd where I can write endpoint for docker registry with "http". To my mind it is not comfortable to add section for every new node in k8s-cluster.

Could you help me find more elegant decision?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd)

Comment: Yes, i did the same. But it not elegant decision, because i need to do it on every node in cluster.