# Pulling images from an insecure registry - on containerd

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, containerd

I have a docker registry(insecure) on my bastion/jumpbox.

We are running Kubernetes and I am trying to run a pod on a cluster that pulls an image from this registry. Since containerd is the container runtime, it throws an error ( ImagePullBackOff ):

`Failed to pull image "1.1.1.2:4657/82d4bb7b89/dockerimages/abc:v2.3.0":   http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`

It looks like with the ctr cli we could use **--plain-http** to pull the image, however,that wouldn't work for this scenario.

Is there any workaround to this error ? Also, we are using "kubectl create -f" to bring up the pod.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor - We ended up applying SSL to the registry and made config.toml changes to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same error .i resloved it by following the steps given below

**sudo rm -rf /etc/containerd/config.toml**

**sudo su -**

**mkdir -p /etc/containerd**

**containerd config default>/etc/containerd/config.toml**

**sudo systemctl restart containerd**

**sudo systemctl enable containerd**

then after these steps open then file

**sudo nano /etc/containerd/config.toml**

find this line

**[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]**

add these 6 lines below that line

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000"]

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000".tls]

```
    ca_file = ""

    cert_file = "" 

    insecure_skip_verify = true 

    key_file = ""
```

then search this line
**[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]**

and add the below lines below that line

```
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."registry-ip:5000"] 
      endpoint = ["http://reistry-ip:5000"]
```

after this i restarted containerd

sudo systemctl restart containerd

its working fine after that