# How to pull docker image from a insecure private registry with latest Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I am trying to create a k8s pod with a docker container image from a private insecure registry. With the latest K8s, I get ErrImagePull as it complains of http vs https for the insecure registry.

```
  Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned imagename to xxxx
  Normal   Pulling    7s    kubelet            Pulling image "registry:5000/imagename:v1”
  Warning  Failed     6s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "registry:5000/imagename:v1”: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry:5000/imagename:v1”: failed to resolve reference "registry:5000/imagename:v1”: failed to do request: Head "https://registry:5000/v2/imagename/manifests/v1”: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     6s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    6s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "registry:5000/imagename:v1”
  Warning  Failed     6s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Before the CRI changes for K8s (i.e. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/), this has worked for me when I used to have insecure registry configuration in /etc/docker/daemon.json, however with the new changes in K8s, I am trying to understand what is the right configuration needed here.

On the same node, I am able to pull the image from the insecure registry successfully with “docker pull imagename” (since I have /etc/docker/daemon.json configuration for the insecure registry), and I have also verified with containerd command “ctr -i pull —plain-http imagename”.

What configuration is needed for this to work in a pod.yaml for me to pull this image via “kubectl create -f pod.yaml”. It's just a simple pod.yaml with the image, nothing fancy.

I saw a post on creating secret key for private registry (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), but that requires registry authentication token to create a key. I just tried using /etc/docker/daemon.json to create a regcred, but when I used it in imagePullSecrets in pod.yaml, k8s was still complaining of the same http vs https error.

My /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "insecure-registries": ["registry:5000"]
}
```

I have a new install of K8s, and containerd is the CRI.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar problem recently about not being able to pull images from an insecure private docker registry using containerd only. I will post my solution here in case it works for your question too. Steps below show the details of how I solved it on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS:

```
$ containerd --version\
containerd containerd.io 1.6.4 212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
```

insecure private docker registry running at 17.5.20.23:5000

The file `/etc/containerd/config.toml` gets created automatically when you install docker using `.deb` packages in ubuntu looks as follows:

```
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"
```

In my first few attempts I was editing this file (which is created automatically) by simply adding the appropriate lines mentioned at [Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd) at the end of the file and restarting containerd. This made the file look as follows:

```
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."17.5.20.23:5000"]
      endpoint = ["http://17.5.20.23:5000"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."17.5.20.23:5000".tls]
      insecure_skip_verify = true
```

This did not work for me. To know why, I checked the configurations with which containerd was running (after `/etc/containerd/config.toml` was edited) using:

```
$ sudo containerd config dump
```

The output of the above command is shown below:

```
disabled_plugins = []
imports = ["/etc/containerd/config.toml"]
oom_score = 0
plugin_dir = ""
required_plugins = []
root = "/var/lib/containerd"
state = "/run/containerd"
temp = ""
version = 2

[cgroup]
  path = ""

[debug]
  address = ""
  format = ""
  gid = 0
  level = ""
  uid = 0

[grpc]
  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  gid = 0
  max_recv_message_size = 16777216
  max_send_message_size = 16777216
  tcp_address = ""
  tcp_tls_ca = ""
  tcp_tls_cert = ""
  tcp_tls_key = ""
  uid = 0

[metrics]
  address = ""
  grpc_histogram = false

[plugins]

  [plugins."io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"]
    deletion_threshold = 0
    mutation_threshold = 100
    pause_threshold = 0.02
    schedule_delay = "0s"
    startup_delay = "100ms"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/opt/containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"]
    interval = "10s"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing"]
    sampling_ratio = 1.0
    service_name = "containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"]
    content_sharing_policy = "shared"

  [plugins."io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"]
    no_prometheus = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"]
    no_shim = false
    runtime = "runc"
    runtime_root = ""
    shim = "containerd-shim"
    shim_debug = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"]
    platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
    sched_core = false
 
  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"]
    default = ["walking"]

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"]
    rdt_config_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"]
    async_remove = false
    base_image_size = ""
    discard_blocks = false
    fs_options = ""
    fs_type = ""
    pool_name = ""
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"]
    root_path = ""
    upperdir_label = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp"]
    endpoint = ""
    insecure = false
    protocol = ""

[proxy_plugins]

[stream_processors]

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar"

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar.gzip"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip"

[timeouts]
  "io.containerd.timeout.bolt.open" = "0s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.cleanup" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.load" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.shutdown" = "3s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.task.state" = "2s"

[ttrpc]
  address = ""
  gid = 0
  uid = 0
```

In the above output I noticed that the configurations I was trying to add by editing the `/etc/containerd/config.toml` were actually not there. So somehow containerd was not accepting the added configurations. To fix this I decided to start from scratch by generating a full configuration file and editing it appropriately (according to instructions at [Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd)).

First took a backup of the current containerd configuration file:

```
$ sudo su
$ cd /etc/containerd/
$ mv config.toml config_bkup.toml
```

Then generated a fresh full configuration file:

```
$ containerd config default > config.toml
```

This generated a file that looked as follows:

```
disabled_plugins = []
imports = []
oom_score = 0
plugin_dir = ""
required_plugins = []
root = "/var/lib/containerd"
state = "/run/containerd"
temp = ""
version = 2

[cgroup]
  path = ""

[debug]
  address = ""
  format = ""
  gid = 0
  level = ""
  uid = 0

[grpc]
  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  gid = 0
  max_recv_message_size = 16777216
  max_send_message_size = 16777216
  tcp_address = ""
  tcp_tls_ca = ""
  tcp_tls_cert = ""
  tcp_tls_key = ""
  uid = 0

[metrics]
  address = ""
  grpc_histogram = false

[plugins]

  [plugins."io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"]
    deletion_threshold = 0
    mutation_threshold = 100
    pause_threshold = 0.02
    schedule_delay = "0s"
    startup_delay = "100ms"

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
    device_ownership_from_security_context = false
    disable_apparmor = false
    disable_cgroup = false
    disable_hugetlb_controller = true
    disable_proc_mount = false
    disable_tcp_service = true
    enable_selinux = false
    enable_tls_streaming = false
    enable_unprivileged_icmp = false
    enable_unprivileged_ports = false
    ignore_image_defined_volumes = false
    max_concurrent_downloads = 3
    max_container_log_line_size = 16384
    netns_mounts_under_state_dir = false
    restrict_oom_score_adj = false
    sandbox_image = "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6"
    selinux_category_range = 1024
    stats_collect_period = 10
    stream_idle_timeout = "4h0m0s"
    stream_server_address = "127.0.0.1"
    stream_server_port = "0"
    systemd_cgroup = false
    tolerate_missing_hugetlb_controller = true
    unset_seccomp_profile = ""

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      conf_template = ""
      ip_pref = ""
      max_conf_num = 1

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]
      default_runtime_name = "runc"
      disable_snapshot_annotations = true
      discard_unpacked_layers = false
      ignore_rdt_not_enabled_errors = false
      no_pivot = false
      snapshotter = "overlayfs"

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime.options]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          base_runtime_spec = ""
          cni_conf_dir = ""
          cni_max_conf_num = 0
          container_annotations = []
          pod_annotations = []
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_path = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"

          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            BinaryName = ""
            CriuImagePath = ""
            CriuPath = ""
            CriuWorkPath = ""
            IoGid = 0
            IoUid = 0
            NoNewKeyring = false
            NoPivotRoot = false
            Root = ""
            ShimCgroup = ""
            SystemdCgroup = false

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime.options]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".image_decryption]
      key_model = "node"

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      config_path = ""

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
      tls_cert_file = ""
      tls_key_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/opt/containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"]
    interval = "10s"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing"]
    sampling_ratio = 1.0
    service_name = "containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"]
    content_sharing_policy = "shared"

  [plugins."io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"]
    no_prometheus = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"]
    no_shim = false
    runtime = "runc"
    runtime_root = ""
    shim = "containerd-shim"
    shim_debug = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"]
    platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
    sched_core = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"]
    default = ["walking"]

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"]
    rdt_config_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"]
    async_remove = false
    base_image_size = ""
    discard_blocks = false
    fs_options = ""
    fs_type = ""
    pool_name = ""
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"]
    root_path = ""
    upperdir_label = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp"]
    endpoint = ""
    insecure = false
    protocol = ""

[proxy_plugins]

[stream_processors]

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar"

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar.gzip"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip"

[timeouts]
  "io.containerd.timeout.bolt.open" = "0s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.cleanup" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.load" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.shutdown" = "3s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.task.state" = "2s"

[ttrpc]
  address = ""
  gid = 0
  uid = 0
```

Then edited the above file to look as follows (the edited lines have been appended with the comment '# edited line'):

```
disabled_plugins = []
imports = ["/etc/containerd/config.toml"] # edited line
oom_score = 0
plugin_dir = ""
required_plugins = []
root = "/var/lib/containerd"
state = "/run/containerd"
temp = ""
version = 2

[cgroup]
  path = ""

[debug]
  address = ""
  format = ""
  gid = 0
  level = ""
  uid = 0

[grpc]
  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  gid = 0
  max_recv_message_size = 16777216
  max_send_message_size = 16777216
  tcp_address = ""
  tcp_tls_ca = ""
  tcp_tls_cert = ""
  tcp_tls_key = ""
  uid = 0

[metrics]
  address = ""
  grpc_histogram = false

[plugins]

  [plugins."io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"]
    deletion_threshold = 0
    mutation_threshold = 100
    pause_threshold = 0.02
    schedule_delay = "0s"
    startup_delay = "100ms"

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
    device_ownership_from_security_context = false
    disable_apparmor = false
    disable_cgroup = false
    disable_hugetlb_controller = true
    disable_proc_mount = false
    disable_tcp_service = true
    enable_selinux = false
    enable_tls_streaming = false
    enable_unprivileged_icmp = false
    enable_unprivileged_ports = false
    ignore_image_defined_volumes = false
    max_concurrent_downloads = 3
    max_container_log_line_size = 16384
    netns_mounts_under_state_dir = false
    restrict_oom_score_adj = false
    sandbox_image = "17.5.20.23:5000/pause-amd64:3.0" #edited line
    selinux_category_range = 1024
    stats_collect_period = 10
    stream_idle_timeout = "4h0m0s"
    stream_server_address = "127.0.0.1"
    stream_server_port = "0"
    systemd_cgroup = false
    tolerate_missing_hugetlb_controller = true
    unset_seccomp_profile = ""

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      conf_template = ""
      ip_pref = ""
      max_conf_num = 1

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]
      default_runtime_name = "runc"
      disable_snapshot_annotations = true
      discard_unpacked_layers = false
      ignore_rdt_not_enabled_errors = false
      no_pivot = false
      snapshotter = "overlayfs"

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime.options]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          base_runtime_spec = ""
          cni_conf_dir = ""
          cni_max_conf_num = 0
          container_annotations = []
          pod_annotations = []
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_path = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"

          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            BinaryName = ""
            CriuImagePath = ""
            CriuPath = ""
            CriuWorkPath = ""
            IoGid = 0
            IoUid = 0
            NoNewKeyring = false
            NoPivotRoot = false
            Root = ""
            ShimCgroup = ""
            SystemdCgroup = true # edited line

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime.options]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".image_decryption]
      key_model = "node"

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      config_path = ""

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."17.5.20.23:5000"] # edited line

          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."17.5.20.23:5000".tls] # edited line
            ca_file = "" # edited line
            cert_file = "" # edited line
            insecure_skip_verify = true # edited line
            key_file = "" # edited line

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."17.5.20.23:5000"] # edited line
          endpoint = ["http://17.5.20.23:5000"] # edited line

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
      tls_cert_file = ""
      tls_key_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/opt/containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"]
    interval = "10s"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing"]
    sampling_ratio = 1.0
    service_name = "containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"]
    content_sharing_policy = "shared"

  [plugins."io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"]
    no_prometheus = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"]
    no_shim = false
    runtime = "runc"
    runtime_root = ""
    shim = "containerd-shim"
    shim_debug = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"]
    platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
    sched_core = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"]
    default = ["walking"]

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"]
    rdt_config_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"]
    async_remove = false
    base_image_size = ""
    discard_blocks = false
    fs_options = ""
    fs_type = ""
    pool_name = ""
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"]
    root_path = ""
    upperdir_label = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp"]
    endpoint = ""
    insecure = false
    protocol = ""

[proxy_plugins]

[stream_processors]

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar"

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar.gzip"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip"

[timeouts]
  "io.containerd.timeout.bolt.open" = "0s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.cleanup" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.load" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.shutdown" = "3s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.task.state" = "2s"

[ttrpc]
  address = ""
  gid = 0
  uid = 0
```

Then I restarted containerd

```
$ systemctl restart containerd
```

Finally I tried pulling an image from the private registry using `crictl` which pulled it successfully:

```
$ crictl -r unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock 17.5.20.23:5000/nginx:latest
Image is up to date for sha256:0e901e68141fd02f237cf63eb842529f8a9500636a9419e3cf4fb986b8fe3d5d
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem! May I suggest adding comment tag to the edited portion of the file? That would help others locate the code more easily.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I simply added `[[registry]]` field into `/etc/containers/registries.conf` file simply because I was using `crio`

```
[[registry]]
insecure = true
location = "IP ADDRESS"
```

and restart crio

```
systemctl restart crio.service
```

Please refer
https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/main/docs/crio.conf.5.md

Answer (score 0):

I guess you now would have to configure containerd rather than docker to support your insecure registry. This is done in the `/etc/containerd/config.toml`. A config example can be found here:

[Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had seen this post and I have tried adding the config suggested in this post to config.toml and restart containerd, but that did not help. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

to make it more simple

find this line in /etc/containerd/config.toml

**[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]**

add these 6 lines below that line

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000"]

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry-ip:5000".tls]

```
    ca_file = ""

    cert_file = ""

    insecure_skip_verify = true

    key_file = ""
```

then search this line

**[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]**

and add the below lines below that line

```
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."registry-ip:5000"] 
      endpoint = ["http://registry-ip:5000"]
```

after this i restarted containerd

sudo systemctl restart containerd