# error deploying image to kubernetes pod: "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-pod

i've got a kubernetes node, control-plane, which is untainted for deploying pods to. i've got a docker image `sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2`.

i'm signed into docker cli. the daemon.json is set with insecure registry and i can verify with `docker info` :

```
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: sdmay2342
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

i can pull the image:

```
Status: Image is up to date for sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2
sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2
```

i can build a container from the image:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
ad582a4d514b   sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds    3000/tcp                                    test-frontend
```

when i deploy it to the node from  yaml manifest, i get an error.
basic manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: test-pod
spec:
   containers:
   - name: test-container
     image: sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2
     ports:
     - containerPort: 6379
```

command: `sudo kubectl create -f test-deploy.yaml`
response: `pod/test-pod created`

the description of the pod:

```
Name:             test-pod
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             sdmay23-42/10.29.160.55
Start Time:       Sun, 27 Nov 2022 18:46:54 +0000
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.244.0.116
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.0.116
Containers:
  test-container:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2
    Image ID:       
    Port:           6379/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-bvwzz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-bvwzz:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  51s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-pod to sdmay23-42
  Normal   BackOff    23s (x2 over 50s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2"
  Warning  Failed     23s (x2 over 50s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    12s (x3 over 50s)  kubelet            Pulling image "sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2"
  Warning  Failed     12s (x3 over 50s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2": failed to resolve reference "sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/canvas-lti-frontend:v2": failed to do request: Head "https://sdmay23-42.ece.iastate.edu:5000/v2/canvas-lti-frontend/manifests/v2": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     12s (x3 over 50s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Comment: This has been asked before. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419513/how-to-pull-docker-image-from-a-insecure-private-registry-with-latest-kubernetes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893120/kubernetes-pull-from-insecure-docker-registry

Comment: Try the steps described [here](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-293609804) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @user2311578. It took awhile to figure out, but Kubernetes uses containerd, not docker. I was able to use the responses from the first link to figure out the insecure registry for containerd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the solution was to configure containerd to accept insecure registries. i had thought kubernetes was using docker. you can do `kubectl get nodes -o wide` to see information about container runtime.

steps for configuring containrd here: [How to pull docker image from a insecure private registry with latest Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419513/how-to-pull-docker-image-from-a-insecure-private-registry-with-latest-kubernetes).