# How to allow ContainerD to connect to insecure docker registry

Tags: docker, containerd

I have install a docker registry:

```
reg_name='kind-registry'
reg_port='5001'
docker run \
    -d --restart=always -p "0.0.0.0:${reg_port}:5000" --name "${reg_name}" \
    registry:2
```

I have then install Kubernetes on Ubuntu, how can I allow Kubernetes to pull from the registry?

I found this:

https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/f033f6ff85ce397202ee69de22b4e3a4bf4093f5/docs/cri/registry.md

Saying the following is deprecated:

[Adding insecure registry in containerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681045/adding-insecure-registry-in-containerd)

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."<IP>:5000"]
      endpoint = ["http://<IP>:5000"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."<IP>:5000".tls]
      insecure_skip_verify = true
```

Non of them worked - do you know how to allow ContainerD to connect to a Docker container running Registry:2?

Note: This is for development only, so insecure is ok